# How can I playback an audio stream from a Icecast on WP7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, streaming, icecast

How can I playback an audio stream from a Icecast on WP7

I have tried SMF, SmoothStreaming Client and the MediaElement.

None of these have worked. The formats are either asx or and wma.

Edit:

Recently I found a new stream. this stream works when I'm in the designer. But it does not work on the device. On the device the stream is opened and closed immediately.

this stream is from an IceCast server in MP3 format. with a ?.mp3 extention. or without.

Comment: probably need a lot more info than that.  What format is it?  what have you tried, what hasn't worked?  Right now the question is really too general to get a great answer other than "see `MediaElement` or `MediaPlayer` or `SoundEffect`" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are streaming live radio, the stream may be encoded by an IceCast server or ShoutCast server. To read these streams, you will need to decode the stream in memomry and pass it to the MediaElement once it has been decoded.

have a look at [Mp3MediaStreamSource](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers)

and [Audio output from Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585868/audio-output-from-silverlight)

I lost tons of time on this, and this is the best solution I found so far.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a quick look at the Icecast web site (I'm not familiar with their service) it seems that most of what they offer for streamed audio is offered in MP3 format, but that they provide this as playlists in either M3U or XSPF format. You can't provide this to any of the built-in controls or classes in the WP7 framework, but you can parse the contents of the file and pass that to a MediaElement to play individual files.

The M3U file is a simple list of the consituent URLs, so is the simplest to deal with, but the XSPF format (which is an XML format) provides more information, such as the title. You can easily use the XDocument class to parse the XSPF file and then use LINQ to query the contents.

Comment: I have triedc to take the url used by winamp to play the stream, I also trieds to rip the url from the m3u file its self but was unable to get the stream to play.

Comment: If you can show us an example of the file you're trying to process (M3U presumably) and it's contents and what code you're using to try to process and play the contents, then we might be able to help a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding the ?.mp3 to the pls file right, to the embedded URL? IF you are using the URL you get from the PLS/M3U file, you might need to append a file extension to it. You can often do this by adding ?ext=.mp3 or ?file.mp3 to the URL and it should play with MediaElement, as I read on the MS dev boards that people had been getting that to work with Shoutcast streams.

Comment: I will try with the ?ext=.mp3 instead of ?.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Does your stream work on the device when you unplug it from the computer? Media playing doesn't work while you're plugged into the Zune sync center.

Chris

Comment: no the media stream does not seem to be in a supported format. I may need to decode it in memory before passing it to a MediaElement as a MediaElementSource