# WP7 audio stream problem

Tags: audio, windows-phone-7, stream

I'm using MediaElement to play audio mp3 stream,
 everything goes ok, but now I have mp3 stream that does not end with .mp3,
 ( http://server2.fmstreams.com:8011/spin103) and I'm getting

AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR

I found solution to add ?ext=mp3, but it didn't work for me,  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are streaming live radio, the stream may be encoded by an IceCast server or ShoutCast server. To read these streams, you will need to decode the stream in memomry and pass it to the MediaElement once it has been decoded.

have a look at **Mp3MediaStreamSource** : http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers

and [Audio output from Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585868/audio-output-from-silverlight)

I lost tons of time on this, and this is the best solution I found so far.

You also have to be sure that while you are testing, the device must be unplugged from the computer.

Comment: http://217.73.28.42:8000/aligator-128.mp3  is also IceCast, and works fine without mp3MediaStreamSource,  why?

Comment: you have an extention and the encoding may be one that is supported by the MediaElement. I was unable to play any IceCast streams without the Mp3MediaStreamSource.

Comment: furthermore, be sure that you are trying to play the actual stream and not the play list.

Comment: Thank you Alexandre, It realy seams that mp3MediaStreamSource could help,
 but I'm having problems with example, RequestCallback is never called,
  can you give me litle hint?