# Playing background live-streaming audio

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, live-streaming

Can anybody give me a link to a working example of playing background **live-streaming** audio in Window Phone 7 (or 7.1)? I saw a lot of examples (in microsoft.com too) and noone of them   works correctly for playing a background live-streaming audio.

FYI, here's an url of live-streaming audio http://radiozetmp3-02.eurozet.pl:8400/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background audio is not supported on 7.0, only 7.1 (and above).

If you want to play streaming audio in a [format/codec which is not natively supported by the phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) you must do it with an `AudioStreamingAgent`. If it is a supported codec, you can use an `AudioPlayerAgent` (see sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Media)).

Using an AudioStreamingAgent is a nontrivial task and requires a deep understanding of the codec you need to play so you can convert it to something the phone understands. I know of one person who did this, for a H.264 stream, and it took a long time and much hair pulling to get it working. And before anyone asks: No, they are not able to share code from that project.

If you really must go down this route, the [ManagedMediaHelpers](https://github.com/loarabia/ManagedMediaHelpers) (previously [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ManagedMediaHelpers)) are a good place to start, but yes, they don't cover all codecs and this is, potentially, **very** complicated and not something well documented on the web.

Comment: This sample doesn't work for live-streaming audio. That's why I'm looking for a working example.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov I've known someone build a streaming client based on that sample. **IT ALL DEPENDS ON THE CODEC THOUGH.** You'll have to understand and convert the codec yourself if necessary. Rather than just complain that existing samples don't work with your stream, look to understand why and ask more specific questions.

Comment: That example uses `new AudioTrack(null, "A#/Bb note", null, null, null, "466.16", EnabledPlayerControls.All)` to play ...stream? If I use `new AudioTrack(new Uri(@"http://radiozetmp3-02.eurozet.pl:8400/", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), "A note", null, null, null, "440", EnabledPlayerControls.All)` it's not working for some reason. I don't know why.

Comment: See [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106124/wp7-audio-stream-problem) for an explanation of your problem.